# Why does iPods need password when installing an app

Tags: ipod

When I try to install an app it said I my passwords wrong and I forgot it but it still wouldn't let me install

Comment: iOS apps are not device-dependant, they are ID-dependant. No account credentials, no install. Start at http://iforgot.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

It always needs a Password for all Installs to protect you, or in case of App Store to identify you and your account.

You could change that settings but I would not advice that.

If it is your Apple ID then you can recover the password using the

https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid

It will send you a email to the account you used allowing you to reset the password or you can answer the questions to which you provided the answer when registering.

[image]